# Is $(H_0^1,\|\cdot\|_{L^2})$ a closed subspace of $L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let $-\infty<a<b<\infty$ and $f\in L^2(a,b)$.

Suppose $(f_n)$ is a sequence in $H_0^1(a,b)$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_{L^2}\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$.

Can we conclude that $f\in H_0^1(a,b)$?

Comment: No, we cannot. $C_c^\infty((a,b))$ is dense in $L^2((a,b))$, hence a fortiori $H_0^1$.

Comment: Of course not. If $I:X\to Y$ is compact, with $X\subset Y$, and $X$ is closed in $Y$, then $X$ is finite dimensional!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel Fischer [gave a good reason](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer) already, but here is a concrete example: $(a,b)=(-1,1)$, 
$$f(x)= \begin{cases}\frac{n}{n-1}(1-x), \quad &x>1/n \\ nx, \quad &0\le x\le 1/n \\ 0, \quad &x<-1/n\end{cases}$$
The functions $f_n$ converge in $L^2$ norm to 
$$f(x)= \begin{cases}1-x, \quad &x>0 \\ 0, \quad &x\le 0  \end{cases}$$
which is not in $H^1_0(a,b)$.